# Valid JSON format to share text to a particular contact in Google Glass Mirror API?

Tags: json, text, share, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I'm playing around with Google Mirror API and creating out some sample apps. Since I'm not an explorer I'm using [Sturm's Mirror API](https://github.com/Scarygami/mirror-api).

I'd like to know the valid JSON format to share a piece of text to a particular Google Glass contact. I tried the following JSON in [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) but got a 400 bad request error. Also is there a way to do the same through [Google Glass Playground](https://developers.google.com/glass/playground) rather than API explorer?

```
{
    'recipients': [
        {
            'acceptTypes': [
                'text/plain'
            ],
            'displayName': 'myglassapp',
            'imageUrls': [
                'https://myglassapp.appspot.com/images/welcome.jpg'
            ],
            'id': 'babu_glass_app'
        }
    ],
    'kind': 'mirror#timelineItem',
    'isDeleted': False,
    'text' : 'Hello World',
}
```

**Error:**

```
400 Bad Request

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  118
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Thu, 30 May 2013 08:05:47 GMT
expires:  Thu, 30 May 2013 08:05:47 GMT
server:  GSE
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops.. My bad. Python dict to JSON problem. `False` instead of `false`. And now the card is getting inserted.

```
{
    'recipients': [
        {
            'acceptTypes': [
                'text/plain'
            ],
            'displayName': 'myglassapp',
            'imageUrls': [
                'https://myglassapp.appspot.com/images/welcome.jpg'
            ],
            'id': 'babu_glass_app'
        }
    ],
    'kind': 'mirror#timelineItem',
    'isDeleted': false,
    'text' : 'Hello World',
}
```